# How do I iterate over files/directories with names that do not match a wildcard?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

From within a batch script file, the following code successfully deletes folders that begin with a name preceding *, denoting a wildcard.  How do I write a FOR loop which iterates over the files/folders which don't match? eg; ![*abc]

```
REM Remove unwanted files/directories

FOR /D /r %%G IN ("local\partialFileName*") DO (

            RMDIR /Q /S %%G                 

)
```

Comment: let's say, it depends on the current situation and the regex capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temp dir, move matching files there, delete all that remain, and then move them back.  Since a move on the same drive doesn't require a copy, it will be fast.

```
md ..\foo
move *abc ..\foo
rd . /s /q 
move ..\foo\* .
rd ..\foo
```

The first rd command will generate an error message, but that can be ignored.